# How do you launch a youtube video from within an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, youtube

How do you launch a youtube video from within an iPad app?

Comment: Seems not to difficult when I google it. E.g. http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application says embed a UIWebView

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Open the YouTube app, or play the video from within your app?

Comment: Trying to play an app at the initial/first start of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *stringURL = @"/*your youtube video URL/*";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: All openURL requests sent to youtube.com automatically open the YouTube app.

Comment: when the user finishes watching the viedo are the brought back to my app ? if not is it possible to do that